# How do i count str_split output according to required

Tags: php, string, split

In my achievement i want to get the result of total  complete number of      $disp[$i] output 
    example

```
      $txt = "12345678910"; 
      $disp = str_split($txt, 4); 
      for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)           { 
       echo $disp[$i]; 

       }
```

In result i have 1234, 5678, 910 that is 2 completed result output
    and 1 uncompleted result output can i just count the completed result output only? 
    Example i want to count the complete result only like 1234, 5678 only i have tried:

```
       $txt = "12345678910"; 
       $disp = str_split($txt, 4); 
       $countA = count($disp); 
       for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)          { 
      if(strlen($disp[$i]) != 4)
       {  
      $countb += count($disp[$i]); 
       echo "$countb"; #Unknow result
       }
      else
       { 
       echo "$counta"; #Good result
       } 
       }
```

thanks for reading and your impact in my solution

Comment: Simple mathematics should tell you: `floor(strlen($txt) / 4)`

Comment: @mark baker
am confuse about your solution please make it more good as answer thanks your impact

Comment: You want to count the complete results of splitting a string of 10 bytes into blocks of 4..... `strlen($txt)` is `10`; divide that by `4` (`10 / 4`) gives `2.5`; using `floor(2.5)` gives `2`.... that is your number of complete results

Comment: Then just use that value in `for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)` instead of `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$txt = "12345678910";
$disp = str_split($txt, 4);
$counta='';
$countb='';

foreach($disp as $disper){
    if(strlen($disper) != 4)
    {
        $countb += count($disper);

    }
    else
    {
        $counta += count($disper);

    }
}
echo $countb ."unknown result"; #Unknow result
echo '<br>';
echo $counta ."good result" . "\r\n"; #Good result
echo '<br>';
```

And the output is :

```
1unknown result
2good result
```

if you don't want to see unknown result just remove the echo for it. $countb variable will still have the actual value if you need to use it.

Comment: I just want to count the output result for disp[$i] as sayed my code cant i achieve it useing my method in php?

Comment: your code has an error in the last echo. It should be $countA not $counta

Comment: Can you please provide the output you want to see?

Comment: Want to count the complete result of $disp[$i]
example 
     $pin = "12345678910"; 
    $disp = str_split($pin, 4); 
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){ 
echo $disp[$i];
output is [1]1234 [2]5678 [3]910
1 and 2 have complete required result character of 1234 and 5678  but 3 has uncompleted result characters 910 so i need count 1 and 2 couse they has required characters thanks for your understanding

Comment: What do you mean count? count function will return 4 for both of them according to your code you can even set it static in your if loop.

Comment: Maybe i cant achieve that in php have also try using your method i got error $pin = "12345678910"; 
    $disp = str_split($pin, 4); 
 for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){ 
foreach($disp[$i] as $disper){ 
        if(strlen($disper) != 4)
{  
$countb += count($disper);
echo "$countb"; #Unknow result
}
else
{ 
echo "$disp[$i]"; #Good result
 } 
 }
}